# Show divisors of a number in a listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, dialog, listbox, numericupdown

I'm trying to get the divisors from a number which the user puts in a `NumericUpDown` form and display an array of those numbers in a listbox (I'm using a form to do this).

Comment: There is no NumericUpDown in Visual C++! I think you mean C# instead of Visual C++!

Comment: There is, but the question was if you know an algorithm to show an array of divisors in a listbox, anyway.

Comment: People here will not do homework. Try yourself to do an algorithm and then when you have doubts or something difficult come here to ask. It is not me being rude; it is the way this site is designed to work.